# Saxon XSLT. Extended functions called only once

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I tried to do XSLT transform one XML file to another XML used XSLT generated in Altova Map Force.

At first, I had the problem when saxon processor can't found Altova specific functions described here: http://manual.altova.com/stylevision/stylevisionenterprise/index.html?fxaltova_xpxqnumeric.htm

functions that used in my XSLT is "generate-auto-number" and    "reset-auto-number".

The problem was "Error at xsl:variable on line 41 column 85 of AltovaXSLT.xslt:
  XPST0017 XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 41 near ...r('mapforce_autonumber_153336056'):
    Cannot find a matching 4-argument function named ://www.altova.com/xslt-extensions}reset-auto-number()"

I solve this problem by using registerExtensionFunction in saxon processor.

But, my functions called only once. In output XML a can see my generated numbers but always the same number.
What i do wrong, please help?

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Results xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PassThrough.xsd"
         FileType="Snapshot"
         ODMVersion="1.3.2"
         dataSet="1.0.0"
         FileOID="482ea709-3e9c-46f5-86ed-1344963b81a4"
         CreationDtateTime="2015-09-28T11:51:59.548-04:00">
   <Study StudyOID="Some Study OID">
      <MetadataInfo MetadataVersionOID="v1.3.2" MetadataVersionName="Version 1.3.2"/>
      <StudyName>Some name</StudyName>
      <StudyDescription/>
      <ProtocolName>Some name</ProtocolName>
   </Study>
   <Patient StudyOID="Some study OID"
            SubjectKey="11"
            MetaDataVersionOID="v1.3.2"
            Visit="SE.week_24_arm_1">
      <Item StudyEventOID="SE.day_1_arm_1"
            FormOID="FM.subject_enrollment_form"
            ItemGroupOID="IG.subject_enrollment_form"
            ItemOID="IT.record_id"
            ItemValue="11"/>
      <Item StudyEventOID="SE.day_1_arm_1"
            FormOID="FM.demographics"
            ItemGroupOID="IG.demographics"
            ItemOID="IT.dm_sex"
            ItemValue="F"/>
      <Item StudyEventOID="SE.day_1_arm_1"
            FormOID="FM.demographics"
            ItemGroupOID="IG.demographics"
            ItemOID="IT.dm_ethnic"
            ItemValue="HISPANIC_OR_LATINO"/>
      ........
      ....
      ........
   </Patient>
</Results>
```

XSLT Transform:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
This file was generated by Altova MapForce 2015r4sp1

YOU SHOULD NOT MODIFY THIS FILE, BECAUSE IT WILL BE
OVERWRITTEN WHEN YOU RE-RUN CODE GENERATION.

Refer to the Altova MapForce Documentation for further details.
http://www.altova.com/mapforce
-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:vmf="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/vmf" xmlns:ns0="http://www.altova.com/xslt-extensions" xmlns:ns1="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="vmf ns0 ns1 xs fn">
    <xsl:template name="vmf:vmf1_inputtoresult">
        <xsl:param name="input" select="()"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$input='SE.week_24_arm_2'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="'WEEK 24'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$input='SE.day_28_arm_2'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="'DAY 28'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$input='SE.day_0_arm_2'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="'BASELINE'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$input='SE.day_3_arm_3'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="'DAY 3'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$input='SE.day_7_arm_3'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="'DAY 7'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$input='SE.day_14_arm_3'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="'DAY 14'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$input='SE.day_0_arm_3'">
                <xsl:copy-of select="'BASELINE'"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" byte-order-mark="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var13_Results" as="node()?" select="Results"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="ns0:reset-auto-number('mapforce_autonumber_153336056')"/>
        <ODM xmlns="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3" xmlns:data="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/Dataset-XML/v1.0">
            <xsl:for-each select="$var13_Results[fn:exists(@FileType)]">
                <xsl:attribute name="FileType" namespace="" select="fn:string(@FileType)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var13_Results[fn:exists(@ODMVersion)]">
                <xsl:attribute name="ODMVersion" namespace="" select="fn:string(@ODMVersion)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var13_Results[fn:exists(@dataSet)]">
                <xsl:attribute name="data:DatasetXMLVersion" select="fn:string(@dataSet)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var13_Results[fn:exists(@FileOID)]">
                <xsl:attribute name="FileOID" namespace="" select="fn:string(@FileOID)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var13_Results[fn:exists(@PriorFileOID)]">
                <xsl:attribute name="PriorFileOID" namespace="" select="fn:string(@PriorFileOID)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var13_Results[fn:exists(@Originator)]">
                <xsl:attribute name="Originator" namespace="" select="fn:string(@Originator)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var13_Results[fn:exists(@CreationDtateTime)]">
                <xsl:attribute name="CreationDateTime" namespace="" select="fn:string(@CreationDtateTime)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var13_Results">
                <xsl:variable name="var12_current" as="node()" select="."/>
                <xsl:for-each select="*:Study[fn:namespace-uri() eq '']">
                    <xsl:variable name="var11_StudyOID" as="node()?" select="@StudyOID"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="var10_resultof_exists" as="xs:boolean" select="fn:exists($var11_StudyOID)"/>
                    <ClinicalData>
                        <xsl:if test="$var10_resultof_exists">
                            <xsl:attribute name="StudyOID" namespace="" select="fn:string($var11_StudyOID)"/>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:for-each select="*:MetadataInfo[fn:namespace-uri() eq ''][fn:exists(@MetadataVersionOID)]">
                            <xsl:attribute name="MetaDataVersionOID" namespace="" select="fn:string(@MetadataVersionOID)"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$var12_current/*:Patient[fn:namespace-uri() eq '']">
                            <xsl:variable name="var9_resultof_cast" as="xs:string" select="fn:string(@SubjectKey)"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="var7_resultof_vmf__inputtoresult" as="xs:string?">
                                <xsl:call-template name="vmf:vmf1_inputtoresult">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="fn:string(@Visit)" as="xs:string"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:variable name="var8_resultof_filter" as="node()*" select="*:Item[fn:namespace-uri() eq ''][fn:exists(@ItemOID)]"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="var6_resultof_filter" as="node()*" select="$var8_resultof_filter[(fn:string(@ItemOID) = 'IT.dm_race')]"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="var5_resultof_filter" as="node()*" select="$var6_resultof_filter[fn:exists(@ItemValue)]"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="var3_resultof_map" as="item()*">
                                <xsl:for-each select="$var5_resultof_filter">
                                    <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(@ItemValue)"/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:variable name="var4_resultof_equal" as="xs:boolean" select="(fn:count($var3_resultof_map) = xs:decimal('1'))"/>
                            <ItemGroupData>
                                <xsl:attribute name="ItemGroupOID" namespace="" select="'IG.DM'"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="var1_resultof_auto_number" as="xs:integer" select="ns0:generate-auto-number('mapforce_autonumber_153336056', xs:integer('1'), xs:integer('1'), '')"/>
                                <xsl:attribute name="data:ItemGroupDataSeq" select="xs:string($var1_resultof_auto_number)"/>
                                <ItemData>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="ItemOID" namespace="" select="'IT.STUDYID'"/>
                                    <xsl:if test="$var10_resultof_exists">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Value" namespace="" select="fn:string($var11_StudyOID)"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </ItemData>
                                <ItemData>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="ItemOID" namespace="" select="'IT.DM.DOMAIN'"/>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Value" namespace="" select="'DM'"/>
                                </ItemData>
                                <ItemData>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="ItemOID" namespace="" select="'IT.USUBJID'"/>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Value" namespace="" select="$var9_resultof_cast"/>
                                </ItemData>
                                <ItemData>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="ItemOID" namespace="" select="'IT.DM.SUBJID'"/>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="Value" namespace="" select="$var9_resultof_cast"/>
                                </ItemData>
                                <xsl:for-each select="$var8_resultof_filter[fn:starts-with(fn:string(@ItemOID), 'IT.site_name')][fn:exists(@ItemValue)]">
                                    <ItemData>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="ItemOID" namespace="" select="'IT.DM.SITEID'"/>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Value" namespace="" select="fn:string(@ItemValue)"/>
                                    </ItemData>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:for-each select="$var8_resultof_filter[fn:starts-with(fn:string(@ItemOID), 'IT.dm_birthyr')][fn:exists(@ItemValue)]">
                                    <ItemData>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="ItemOID" namespace="" select="'IT.DM.BRTHDTC'"/>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Value" namespace="" select="fn:string(@ItemValue)"/>
                                    </ItemData>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:for-each select="$var8_resultof_filter[fn:starts-with(fn:string(@ItemOID), 'IT.dm_sex')][fn:exists(@ItemValue)]">
                                    <ItemData>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="ItemOID" namespace="" select="'IT.DM.SEX'"/>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Value" namespace="" select="fn:string(@ItemValue)"/>
                                    </ItemData>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:if test="(fn:not($var4_resultof_equal) or fn:exists($var6_resultof_filter[fn:exists(@ItemValue)]))">
                                    <ItemData>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="ItemOID" namespace="" select="'IT.DM.RACE'"/>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Value" namespace="">
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="$var4_resultof_equal">
                                                    <xsl:variable name="var2_resultof_map" as="xs:string*">
                                                        <xsl:for-each select="$var5_resultof_filter">
                                                            <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(@ItemValue)"/>
                                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                                    </xsl:variable>
                                                    <xsl:sequence select="xs:string(fn:string-join(for $x in $var2_resultof_map return xs:string($x), ' '))"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                    <xsl:sequence select="'MULTIPLE'"/>
                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </ItemData>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:for-each select="$var8_resultof_filter[fn:starts-with(fn:string(@ItemOID), 'IT.dm_ethnic')][fn:exists(@ItemValue)]">
                                    <ItemData>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="ItemOID" namespace="" select="'IT.DM.ETHNIC'"/>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Value" namespace="" select="fn:string(@ItemValue)"/>
                                    </ItemData>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <ItemData>
                                    <xsl:if test="fn:exists($var7_resultof_vmf__inputtoresult)">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="Value" namespace="" select="$var7_resultof_vmf__inputtoresult"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </ItemData>
                            </ItemGroupData>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ClinicalData>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ODM>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the Java code:

```
        Processor processor = new Processor(true);
    processor.registerExtensionFunction(new GenerateAutoNumberExtDefinition());
    processor.registerExtensionFunction(new ResetAutoNumberExtDefinition());

    XdmNode input = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(inputXML);
    Xslt30Transformer transformer = processor.newXsltCompiler().compile(xsltSource).load30();
    StringWriter outputStream = new StringWriter();
    transformer.applyTemplates(input, processor.newSerializer(outputStream));
```

Where the GenerateAutoNumberExtDefinition implement increment of variable. I even try to debug this and I am sure that it's called only once.

And the result XML is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ODM xmlns="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3"
     xmlns:data="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/Dataset-XML/v1.0"
     FileType="Snapshot"
     ODMVersion="1.3.2"
     data:DatasetXMLVersion="1.0.0"
     FileOID="c293a323-31a0-4df3-94b4-2876f62b8193"
     CreationDateTime="2015-10-01T15:41:57.216-04:00">
   <ClinicalData StudyOID="Some OID"
                 MetaDataVersionOID="2015-06-30T09:45:09.000-04:00">
      <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG.DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1">
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.STUDYID" Value="Some OID"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.DOMAIN" Value="DM"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.USUBJID" Value="11"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SUBJID" Value="11"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SEX" Value="F"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.RACE" Value="ASIAN"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.ETHNIC" Value="HISPANIC_OR_LATINO"/>
         <ItemData/>
      </ItemGroupData>
      <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG.DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1">
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.STUDYID" Value="Some OID"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.DOMAIN" Value="DM"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.USUBJID" Value="12"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SUBJID" Value="12"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SEX" Value="M"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.RACE" Value="MULTIPLE"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.ETHNIC" Value="HISPANIC_OR_LATINO"/>
         <ItemData/>
      </ItemGroupData>
      <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG.DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1">
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.STUDYID" Value="Some OID"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.DOMAIN" Value="DM"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.USUBJID" Value="14"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SUBJID" Value="14"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SEX" Value="M"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.RACE" Value="NATIVE_HAWAIIAN_OR_OTHER_PACIFIC_ISLANDER"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.ETHNIC" Value="NOT_HISPANIC_OR_LATINO"/>
         <ItemData/>
      </ItemGroupData>
      <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG.DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1">
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.STUDYID" Value="Some OID"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.DOMAIN" Value="DM"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.USUBJID" Value="12344"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SUBJID" Value="12344"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SEX" Value="UNDIFFERENTIATED"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.RACE" Value="MULTIPLE"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.ETHNIC" Value="UNKNOWN"/>
         <ItemData/>
      </ItemGroupData>
      <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG.DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1">
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.STUDYID" Value="Some OID"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.DOMAIN" Value="DM"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.USUBJID" Value="22333"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SUBJID" Value="22333"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.RACE" Value="MULTIPLE"/>
         <ItemData/>
      </ItemGroupData>
      <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG.DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1">
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.STUDYID" Value="Some OID"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.DOMAIN" Value="DM"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.USUBJID" Value="22334"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SUBJID" Value="22334"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.RACE" Value="MULTIPLE"/>
         <ItemData/>
      </ItemGroupData>
      <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG.DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1">
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.STUDYID" Value="Some OID"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.DOMAIN" Value="DM"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.USUBJID" Value="22335"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SUBJID" Value="22335"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.RACE" Value="MULTIPLE"/>
         <ItemData/>
      </ItemGroupData>
      <ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="IG.DM" data:ItemGroupDataSeq="1">
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.STUDYID" Value="Some OID"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.DOMAIN" Value="DM"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.USUBJID" Value="22336"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SUBJID" Value="22336"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.SEX" Value="F"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.RACE" Value="MULTIPLE"/>
         <ItemData ItemOID="IT.DM.ETHNIC" Value="NOT_REPORTED"/>
         <ItemData/>
      </ItemGroupData>
   </ClinicalData>
</ODM>
```

as you can see in each data:ItemGroupDataSeq the value is "1" but it's should increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually way described above is worked. But not for my specific case, when i need some times reset counter and start count again (what function  is doing).

But it's problem I can solve by overriding function dependsOnFocus in ExtensionFunctionDefinition class.

```
@Override
public boolean dependsOnFocus() {
    return true;
}
```

If the value is false, it's looks like a cache. If parameters not changes, that the function called only once. Returning true by dependsOnFocus method allow us depend on function position in xslt not on parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you solve that simply with pure XSLT? `<xsl:attribute name="data:ItemGroupDataSeq"><xsl:number/></xsl:attribute>` or even `<xsl:attribute name="data:ItemGroupDataSeq" select="position()"/>` inside the `for-each` over `Patient` elements should do.

If you need help with the extension functions then we need to see their implementation.

Comment: Thank you for help. Actually your way is worked. But not for my specific case, when i need some times reset counter and start count again (what function <xsl:sequence select="ns0:reset-auto-number('mapforce_autonumber_153336056')"/> is doing).